# testNG: force execution of @Before* even if there are failures in previous calls

Tags: ant, testng

I'd like to disable the testNG behavior which skips all *Before methods if there there is an error/ exception in one during the test run.

Normally, this is desired, but in my case these failures are sporadic and I want to actually continue with the test run, and execute the *Before methods.

Thanks for any help!
-Denali

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you catch these exceptions, then? It's better to explicitly put catch{} where you think they are needed rather than ignoring everything blindly, which means you might miss an important exception at some point.